# CSS large space before div on left when having two divs on right under each other

Tags: css, html

I am developing a social network and am having some problems with my profile pages. So what I am doing is having three divs (as an example). One being the main 'post' part, the other two being the 'about me' and 'friends' section. I have the post one floating on the left, and the sidebars floating on the right. When I have two divs on the sidebar on the right, the post div will not go directly under the cover, there will be a giant space there as if there were an invisible div there http://prntscr.com/3988wj
Here is my html

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-container">
        <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="sidebar-header">About</div>
            <div class="sidebar-list">Birthday: <b>09/05/2000</b></div>
            <div class="sidebar-list">Gender: <b>Male</b></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-container">
        <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="sidebar-header">Friends</div>
            <div class="sidebar-list">Birthday: <b>09/05/2000</b></div>
            <div class="sidebar-list">Gender: <b>Male</b></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="message">
    <div class="message-container">
    <div class="message-content">
        <div class="message-padding">
            <div class="message-avatar"><img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>"></div>
            <div class="message-author"><a href=""><?php echo $user; ?></a></div>
            <div class="message-date">12/04/2014</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
#message {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20%;
    width: 44.4%;
}
.message-padding {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.message-container {
    padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.message-content {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #CCC;
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    background: #fff;
    color: #6B6B6B;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.message-avatar {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.message-avatar img {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.message-author {
    color: #3A5796;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, 'Segoe UI', Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.message-author a {
    color: #3A5796;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, 'Segoe UI', Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.message-date {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, 'Segoe UI', Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 19.49%;
    width: 16%;
    clear:both;
}
.sidebar-container {
    padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.sidebar-list {
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.sidebar-content {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #CCC;
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    background: #fff;
    color: #6B6B6B;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.sidebar-header {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Is there any way to make it so the post div goes in the right place, and so other post divs can go under it, and other divs in the sidebar? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the two sidebars in a div together and float that div to the right.

Actually, you can make the two divs with id "sidebar" into one div. Having two elements with the same id is invalid anyway.

So the HTML for that part looks like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-container">
        <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="sidebar-header">About</div>
            <div class="sidebar-list">Birthday: <b>09/05/2000</b></div>
            <div class="sidebar-list">Gender: <b>Male</b></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Here closing and re-opening the div is removed -->

    <div class="sidebar-container">
        <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="sidebar-header">Friends</div>
            <div class="sidebar-list">Birthday: <b>09/05/2000</b></div>
            <div class="sidebar-list">Gender: <b>Male</b></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result will look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/48BfU/

Comment: Genius! Thank you, I didn't even think of doing that